# ASP .NET Core 3.1 IOC - Inject only some parameters, pass others

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, inversion-of-control

I was looking for a way or a pattern to being able to pass only some parameters to a class and inject others.

**The idea is:**

- Param is a parameter I pass to the constructor
- Inject is something IOC has to take care of

Calling class would be like

```
new ClassToCreate(param, param, inject)
```

In which the third param is one I don't want to pass.

**The scenario:**

I will picture briefly the scenario and how I got to this, so **maybe someone has a way smarter solution**.

I am working on a project that interacts with SQL database, with a unit of work and repository pattern.

A small extract of the Unit of work class:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MYPROJECT.ILIKETHISPROJECT.Dependencies.Repositories
{
    public sealed class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        public IDbConnection connection { get; set; }
        public IDbTransaction transaction { get; set; }
        private IRegistryRepository registryRepository;
        private IConfiguration configuration;

    private bool disposed;

    public UnitOfWork(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        connection.Open();
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    //Recovers data from a table called Registry
    public IRegistryRepository registry
    {
        get => registryRepository ?? new RegistryRepository(this, configuration, INJECT ME!!!, INJECT ME TOO!!!!);
        set => registryRepository = value;
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        //DO COMMIT
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
       // DO ROLLBACK
    }

    private void ResetRepositories()
    {
        registry = null;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //DO DISPOSE (IDisposable interface requires both dispose signatures)
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        //DO DISPOSE
    }

    ~UnitOfWork()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Concentrate on the

> ```
> new RegistryRepository(this, configuration, INJECT ME!!!, INJECT ME TOO!!!!);
> ```

part. Here I have to pass unito of work to the repository, and the configuration (because I will fetch some params.

Now, the RegistryRepository constructory is:

```
public RegistryRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IConfiguration configuration, IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider, DataProtectionPurposeStrings dataProtectionPurposeStrings)
```

The class to be injected automagically would be

- IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider
- DataProtectionPurposeStrings dataProtectionPurposeStrings

What they do is encrypt/decrypt some strings and my aim is to store and encrypted password in appsettings.json configuration file of a NET. CORE 3.1 WebApi.

The idea come from [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlHDTQhVYoI) which uses data protection included in net core.

Basically I need to pass the first two parameters, and I would like to let IOC take care of the rest.

If not possible, I would have to modify UnitOfWork constructor this way:

```
public UnitOfWork(IConfiguration configuration, IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider, DataProtectionPurposeStrings dataProtectionPurposeStrings)
```

And then pass the two instantiated classes to RegistryRepository.

Is there a better way/idea to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

```
//...

get => registryRepository ?? ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<RegistryRepository>(
    serviceProvider, this, configuration);

//...
```

but you will need an injected service provider which will act as the IoC container to resolve the other parameters that were not provided.

I would however suggest rethinking your current design about injecting `IConfiguration` and also tightly coupling to concrete implementation concerns like `SqlConnection`.

It appears the current design is highly dependent on run time data.

Comment: Could you expand on that?
I mean, how to use Activator + IServiceProvider (can't find an example around) and on how to redesign the code? It's not very clear like that

Thanks